# С++ программа для устного счета

Tags: c++

почему-то выбирает действие кроме деления почему ???

```
#include <iostream>//подключаем стандартную библеотеку
#include <ctime>//библеотека для работы с рандомными числами и временем

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int random1, random2, randop, tanswer, answer, t= 0, diapoz;//числовые переменные
    string name;//символьная переменная
    bool over = true, dia = true;//
    {
        cout <<"как тебя зовут?"<<endl;
        cin >> name;// спрашивает и запоминает имя
        cout<< "Привет "<< name <<endl;
        cout <<"Я хочу сыграть с тобой в одну игру на устный счет. Правила простые я задаю тебе пример на сложение , вычитанее или умножение. За каждый праввильный будет прибавляться по 1 очку"<<endl;
    v://точка спавн
        cout <<"выбери дипозон чисел (выбери номер варианта): 1) от 0 до 10 2) от 0 до 100."<<endl;
        cin >> diapoz;//спрашивает диапозон чисел
        while (over) {
        if (diapoz == 1) {//проверяет если diapoz будет равен 1 то он будет выполнять следущую команду
            srand (time(NULL));
            random1 = rand () %  11;//генерирует случайные числа от 0 до 10
            random2 = rand () %  11;

        }
        if (diapoz == 2) {
            srand (time(NULL));
            random1 = rand () %  101;// генерирует случайные числа от 0 до 100
            random2 = rand () %  101;
        }
            if (diapoz != 1 && diapoz != 2) {//проверяет если diapoz будет не равен 1 или 2 то он выполняет следущую команду
                cout <<"непонятная команда!"<<endl;
                goto v;//перекидывает на точку v:

        }
         cout <<"Поехали!\n_______________________"<<endl;

        randop = rand() % 3 +1;//генерирует случайное действие + - * или /

        switch (randop) {
            case 1: ;
                tanswer = random1 + random2;
                cout <<random1<< "+"<<random2<<endl;// +
                break;
            case 2: ;
                tanswer = random1 - random2;
                cout <<random1<< "-"<<random2<<endl;// -
                break;
            case 3: ;
                tanswer = random1 * random2;
                cout <<random1<< "*"<<random2<<endl;// *
                break;
            case 4: ;
                tanswer = random1 / random2;
                cout <<random1<< "/"<<random2<<endl;// /
                break;

        }
        cin >> answer;//спрашивает ответ
        if (answer == tanswer) {//проверяет ваш ответ с другим ответом
            cout <<"Правильно!\n_____________________________";
            cout <<"\n\n";
            t++;//прибавляет по 1 баллу

        }
        else {//иначе если то действие не выполнилось то он выполняет это
            cout <<"Неправильно!  Ответ:"<<tanswer<<endl;
            cout <<"__________________\n\n";
            cout <<"у тебя "<< t <<" правильных ответов"<<endl;
            over = false;//заканчивает игру
        }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x % 3`   это остаток от деления на три, значит может вернуть только 0, 1 или 2.

Comment: Аттакже для случайных чисел есть  и  другой заголовок - `random`. `ctime` - просто старая библиотека работы со временем (в Си++ есть  `chrono`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будте очень внимательны с не инициализированными переменными. Например если

`randop = rand() % 4;`

получит значение 0, то в switch-case вы не попадете ни в оду из ветвей, и переменная `tanswer` останется не инициализированной, те будет содержать мусор.

Проверка `if (answer == tanswer)` в таком случае очень опасна, поэтому ваша программа и работает через раз.

`The variable 'tanswer' is being used without being initialized.`

И отмечу, что от `goto` лучше избавиться, едва ли вы встретите этот оператор в любых других программах. В вашем случае вместо метки `goto` целесообразно использовать цикл `while` с проверкой выхода по достижению правильного ответа